# Backbone, how to ensure that the functions declared inside the view, affect DOM elements from that view only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

The following view is bound to the **cars** element.

When the view is initialized, I load a certain template, which loads a div called **".menu"**.

**Now, I want to do stuff to that menu, fill it with hmtl, and I want only the menu from inside the view to be affected.**

If there is another "menu" on that page, outside the view, it will get affected.

How should I ensure that the JavaScript inside the view affects only elements from that view?

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : '.cars',

    pag : '.pagination',

    initialize : function () {

        var template = _.template(myTemplate, {});

        $(this.el).html(template);

        $('.menu').html('test');
    },

    events : {
    'click .pagination a' : 'click'
},

});
```

I could just do this:

```
$('.cars .menu').html('test');
```

But I think there should be a more elegant solution, like binding the .menu to the view.

The second question....

**If i bind a click event to a div called .pagination inside the view... how can I use a variable in the events object instead writing the element's name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html in the view's `el` can be scoped with `find`:

```
yourView.$el.find(".menu");
```

Or the via the shortcut for the above method:

```
yourView.$(".menu");
```

You can also bind to elements within the view with events, considering your 2nd question:

```
 // in the model definition
 events: {
   // This would only bind to clicks for .pagination elements that are
   // children of the view
   'click .pagination a' : function (e) {
      // You can get at the clicked element via the `currentTarget` property 
      // of the event
      var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
      console.log(href);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I will edit and ask you something else also, maybe you can help. Ty very much:)

Comment: I haven't tested it, the events part (it's like you read my mind) - you are saying that is there is another div called menu, outside the view, it won't be affected by the click?

Comment: That's right.  It uses event delegation via the view's `el`.  Events from inside the element propagate up to it.

Comment: I am working on an app and it's starting to wrap together. It has been hard to learn how to use require, backbone, underscore, templates... but now I can start to see how simple this makes allot of things

Comment: note I edited it to use `currentTarget`.  `target` can be misleading if, for example, you have `span`s inside your link, etc.

Comment: There's also [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) which is the same as `this.$el.find`.